# mysql query current date results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the rows that has been submitted today. the problem is that Im using the following format in the date column and this is how it is submitted:

```
<input type="text" name="lastupdate" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); ?>" readonly>
```

and the following query is the one Im trying to figure out to get the records of only today:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertracker WHERE status='Action.Required' AND lastupdate=CURDATE()");
```

it doesn't give any result, can anyone help me to findout what Im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data-type of your `lastupdate` field? Is it `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: the data type is text. will that be a problem?

Comment: That is a problem, not necessarily "the" problem; if you're storing a date in that column, that column's data-type *should be* a `date` type (or `datetime` if you want to contain the time too)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if I got it but "echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s')" outputs date and time.

CURDATE() according to mysql manual

Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Are you missing in this query the time?

Comment: I need to get results for today's date, not for the exact current date and time

Comment: You may use - lastupdate like "% %" - instead of lastupdate =